# integration of $2x^{2}3^{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the integral

$$\int2x^23^{x^3}dx$$

So doing basic moves and U-sub yields

$$2\int x^23^{x^3}dx$$
$$u=3^{x^3}$$
$$du=3^{x^3+1}x^2\ln(3)$$
Now plugging in with u yields
$$2\int\frac{u}{\ln(3)*3^{\frac{\ln(u)+\ln(3)}{\ln(3)}}}du$$
but from here I am lost, I think this way of solving is too complex. Keep in mind I am reviewing for my Calc 2 test and this type of manipulation of an integral is very foreign to me and not something we have covered in class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints: Let $u=x^3$. Then your integral becomes $$\frac{2}{3}\int 3^u\,du$$
and $\int a^x\,dx=\frac{a^x}{\ln a}+C$.